# I can't user context[:current_resource] graphql_devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, graphql

I installed graphql_devise gem

when I tried to user context[:current_resource], I can't use  `context[:current_resource]`
why?

when I want to use current_user, should i user devise_token_authentication?
I'm in trouble.

please help

thanks

#### configration

install into my schema

```
class MySchema < GraphQL::Schema
  use GraphqlDevise::SchemaPlugin.new(
    query:            Types::QueryType,
    mutation:         Types::MutationType,
    resource_loaders: [
      GraphqlDevise::ResourceLoader.new('User'),
    ],
    authenticate_default: false
  )
  mutation(Types::MutationType)
  query(Types::QueryType)

  # Setup GraphQL to use the built-in lazy_resolve method
  use BatchLoader::GraphQL
end
```

route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # For graphql
  if Rails.env.development?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  end
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute" 
  get "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
```

graqhql_controller.rb:

```
def execute
    variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
    query = params[:query]
    operation_name = params[:operationName]
    result = BusinessCloudSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: graphql_context(:user), operation_name: operation_name)
    render json: result unless performed?
  rescue => e
    raise e unless Rails.env.development?
    handle_error_in_development e
  end
```

user_update_input.rb

```
module Types
  class UserUpdateInput < Types::BaseInputObject
    argument :fist_name, String, required: true
    argument :last_name, String, required: true
    argument :position, String, required: false
    argument :image, ApolloUploadServer::Upload, required: false

    def update!
      current_user.assign_attributes(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, image: valid_image)
      current_user.update
      {
        errors: user_errors(current_user.errors),
        user: current_user.reload
      }
    end

    private

    def valid_image
      image if image&.is_a?(ApolloUploadServer::Wrappers::UploadedFile)
    end
  end
end
```

update_user.rb

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateUser < BaseMutation
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

    argument :user, Types::UserUpdateInput, required: true

    def resolve(user:)
      {
        user: user.update!
      }
    end
  end
end
```

iI execute the following mutation in graphiql

```
mutation{
  updateUser(input: { clientMutationId: "", user: {fistName: "aa", lastName: "bb", position: "manager"}}) {
    clientMutationId
    user{
      email
      firstName
      image
      lastName
      position
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For this gem you are using you need to add in your user model `app/models/user` this line at end ` include GraphqlDevise::Concerns::Model` and your graphql controller should also inherit your application_controller and your application_controller should include ` include GraphqlDevise::Concerns::SetUserByToken` please check documentation [Documetnation](https://github.com/graphql-devise/graphql_devise)

Comment: thanks!! but already  I added both ```include GraphqlDevise::Concerns::Model ``` and ```include GraphqlDevise::Concerns::SetUserByToken```